# Problem with my OVRPlugin in unity error: EntryPointNotFoundException: ovrp_UnityOpenXR_SetClientVersion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality

So i'm making a vr game for an hackathon and everything was going very well, but after i created a new scene called mainMenu with an actual menu inside the scene, so i tryed to click on play but after that i get some weird error:
"EntryPointNotFoundException: ovrp_UnityOpenXR_SetClientVersion"

and the game fully stopped working.

Any help will be appriciate

[The actual error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRTgT.png)

[Full Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1C5O.png)